# Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing

I get this error with no reason while I was working to a project 
[image]

I already tried (looking in other similar question) to clean the project and delete the derived data without success. How can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem as you. 
Step 1:
Go to terminal and type 'cd ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData'
(Without quotes)
Step 2: 
Write 'xattr -dr com.apple.FinderInfo *'
(Without quotes)
Lastly, open your Xcode project and it should be fixed